# In this sentence, who are sitting on the bench?

Tags: ambiguity, adjuncts

Consider:

> She spoke with him sitting on a bench.

I think it is likely to mean she is sitting on the bench or he is sitting on the bench.

So, I wonder if there is a way to eliminate this ambiguity.

Comment: FYI mate: *is* for singular, *are* for plural - regarding *she*, *he* and *a method*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is ambiguity here—we cannot tell whether it was he or she who sat on the bench, or even both of them. Syntactically the likeliest predicand for *sitting on a bench* is *him*, since such modifiers typically follow their predicands immediately; but as InitK points out, the phrase may act as a secondary predicate modifying the subject, or it may act as a clausal adjunct modifying the entire clause.

No, there is no way of resolving this ambiguity in the sentence itself, though it may be resolved in context.

Answer (score 3):

I think, it's not possible to say who and maybe it's not important in this case. I would still guess though and say it is she who is sitting, because she is the subject of this sentence:

She - spoke - sitting

If it would be he who was sitting it would have to be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

I would say at **first glance** most native speakers would probably **assume both are sitting** on the bench conversing since this is a **natural and ordinary** occurrence, and it is only after the **ambiguity is flagged** that positioning of the two participants becomes questionable.

I think the **next assumption** would be the man is sitting and the woman is not.

I think **much less so** would a listener assume the woman and not the man was sitting.

> 1) She spoke with him sitting on a bench.

is ambiguous

> 2) She spoke with him **while** sitting on a bench

is also ambiguous, but more natural sounding

> 3)
>   **While** sitting on a bench, she spoke with him
>   Sitting on a bench, she spoke with him

**rearranging** the exact same words in #1 and #2, may sound less ambiguous, but still remains unresolved. If anything, there is an emphasis of **she** being seated due to proximity to **sitting**

> 4)
>   **They** spoke *(* with each other *)* while sitting on a bench
>   She spoke to him **while they both sat** on a bench

is unambiguous.

The only way to **resolve** this sentence would be **to change the wording**