# Present perfect + ago for events in the past

Tags: tense, time

If eating starts at 7:00 AM and finishes at 7:30 AM, and the time is now 7:40 AM.

What should I say：

1. Now I have eaten for 40 minutes.
2. 10 minutes ago I have eaten for 30 minutes.

Comment: You sure ask a lot of questions about eating for 30 minutes ten minutes ago!  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78330/when-can-i-say-that-i-ate-for-30-minutes-if-eating-start-at-am-700-and-fin, http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78335/which-should-i-say-i-ate-for-30-minutes-at-700-or-i-ate-for-30-minutes-at-7, http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78310/can-i-say-that-at-am-740-i-ate-for-30-minutes-10-minutes-ago